# How to split Nomenclature into symbols, greek, and subscript groups, but retain alphabetical groups of Abbreviations and Glossary

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

I have a document with Abbreviations, Nomenclature, and Glossary sections. Some nomenclature entries also add glossary terms.

I'd like to split my Nomenclature groupings into something like Symbols, Greek Letters, and Subscripts (with the option to add more as required, e.g. Constants).

I've found a few options (renaming groups A, G, and S and using sort=X), however, this also renames the groups in Abbreviations and Glossary.

How can I have my custom groups apply only to Nomenclature?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{bookmark}
    \bookmarksetup{numbered,open}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newglossary[nlg]{nomenclature}{not}{ntn}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Letters}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Subscripts}

\newacronym{rpm}{rpm}{revolutions per minute}
\newacronym{gdt}{GDT}{Geometric Dimensioning and Tolerancing}

\newglossaryentry{geo}{
        name={geometric},   
        description={relating to geometry, the branch of mathematics...}}

\newglossaryentry{pressure}{type=nomenclature,
    name=\ensuremath{P},
    sort=a,
    description={pressure (\si{\newton\per\square\metre})},
    first={pressure (\ensuremath{P})\glsadd{pressure_g}},
    see=[Glossary:]{pressure_g}}
    \newglossaryentry{pressure_g}{
            name={pressure},
            description={a continuous physical force exerted on or against an object by something in contact with it}}

\newglossaryentry{density}{type=nomenclature,
    name=\ensuremath{\rho},
    sort=g,
    description={density (\si{\kilo\gram\per\cubic\metre})},
    first={density (\ensuremath{\rho})\glsadd{rho_g}},
    see=[Glossary:]{rho_g}}
    \newglossaryentry{rho_g}{
        name={density},
        description={a material's mass per unit volume with units \si{\kilo\gram\per\cubic\metre}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\glossarystyle{listhypergroup}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

\glossarystyle{listhypergroup}
\printglossary[type=nomenclature,title=Nomenclature]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\gls{gdt} and \gls{rpm} are abbreviations. \Gls{geo} is a glossary term. \Gls{pressure} and \gls{density} are nomenclature terms.

\glossarystyle{listhypergroup}
\printglossary[title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```